# Java : Parsing directory and sub-directory to check for files of a particular type

Tags: java

Description : I am trying to parse my main directory to find all the files of type ".jpg" and my code is able to return all the files that are needed. example "C:\Ravi\Sources", in this directory i have mixed files of .xml, .jpg, .gif, now i am also having sub folders inside this directory but i don't know 
how to modify my code to check for sub-directories as well.

Expertise help is required here :

Code Snippet :

```
enter code here




import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class Subdirectory {

    static File f = new File("C:\\Users\\kasharma\\Desktop\\Travelocity R8.3_8.3.0.apk\\res");// File f will represent the folder....

static String[] extensions = new String[]{"png", "jpg", "gif" };  // Declaring array of supported filters...



// Applying filter to identify images based on their extensions...

static FilenameFilter Image_Filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File f, String name)
    {
        for(String ext: extensions){
            if(name.endsWith("."+ ext)){
                return(true);
            }
        }
        return(false);
    }
    };

    public static void goThroughDirectories(String path)
    {

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          String path = "C:\\Users\\kasharma\\Desktop\\Travelocity R8.3_8.3.0.apk\\res";


            for (File file : f.listFiles(Image_Filter)) 
                {
                if (f.isDirectory()) goThroughDirectories(path+f.getName());

                BufferedImage img = null;

                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(file); 
                    System.out.println("image "+ file.getName());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle errors here
                }

        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at `java.nio.files`, especially the `walkFileTree(...)` and `find(...)` methods.  Java 8 includes a builtin capability for this.

Using `walkFileTree`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Path p = Paths.get("D:/");
    Files.walkFileTree(p, 
            new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
                {
                    System.out.println(file.toFile().getName());
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Here's an even better solution using `find` that returns a lazily populated stream and filters for `.jpg` at the same time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Path p = Paths.get("D:/");
    Files
        .find(
            p, 
            Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
            (path,attr) -> path.toString().endsWith(".jpg"))
        .forEach(path -> System.out.println(path.toFile().getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the idea. This is pseudocode.

```
void goThroughDirectories(String path)
{
    for(File f : fileList)
    {
        if(f.isDirectory()) goThroughDirectories(path+f.getName());
        else {
                //do something
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still not helping me as gives error for 'fileList'.

Comment: This is pseudocode. You can't just copy & paste it. In your code it's called f.listFiles(Image_Filter)).

Comment: Should it be put inside main or outside ?

Comment: Since it's a method you need to put it outside of main. Then call it via goTroughDirectories("your/path/to/st"); inside of main.